# Render nested object using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, render, nested-object

Good day guys, I'm having trouble fixing my problem here and I run out of an idea. My error is Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userId, purchasedOn, _id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I'm trying to render my nested object. Also, how can I use useState in nested object.

so far this is my code for the use state;

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
const [cart, setCart] = useState(0); //this is where my nested object is. but it never works
```

This is where I want to render it;

```
export default function ProductCard({productProp}) {

const {_id, name, description, price, cart} = productProp;

return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className="p-3 m-3 justify-context-center">
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Subtitle>Description:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{description}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Subtitle>Price:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>PhP {price}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Subtitle>Here is the nested Object:</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{cart}</Card.Text>
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to={`/products/${_id}`}>View Product</Link>    
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
)
}
```

and here is my back-end model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : {
    type : String,
    required : [true, `name is required`]
},
description : {
    type : String,
    required : [true, `description is required`]
},
price : {
    type : Number,
    required : [true, `Price is required`]
},
isActive : {
    type : Boolean,
    default : true
},
createdOn : {
    type : Date,
    default : new Date()
},
customers : [
        {
            userId : {
                type : String,
                required : [true, "User ID is required"]
        },
            purchasedOn : {
                type : Date,
                default : new Date
        }
}],
cart : [
        {
            userId : {
                type : String,
                required : [true, "User ID is required"]
        },
            purchasedOn : {
                type : Date,
                default : new Date
        }
}]
})
```

note: I can render my object but now the nested object

Comment: It would be easier to solve ur problem if u reproduced it on codesandbox

Comment: Is it possible if you add more code like how you called the component etc? It's hard to tell what's wrong based on what you have.

Comment: thanks for replying, the error is now gone, but now I just can't render the object inside productProp cart.